# Python syntax error when pasting code into terminal with indentation

Tags: python, terminal

When I paste code into the (terminal)/(shell)/(command prompt)/(powershell) that contains indentation and an unindented line after it python either gets `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`, or runs the code as two separate "commands".

This produces a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` error when pasted into the terminal:

```
if True:
 print('first')
print('second')
```

This runs two separate commands when pasted into the terminal:

```
if True:
 print('first')

print('second')
```

The output of the above code looks like this which is undesirable:

```
first
>>>print('second')
second
```

How do I run this as one "command". I'm using Windows 10, python 3.7.8

Comment: Why not just put the code into a file and run that?

Comment: I've encountered three main situations where I needed it:
Debugging code for Blender using Blender's scripting window.
Running python code for work through a special shell where I have no contact to the person who programmed the shell.
Sending debugging code to remote locations to computer illiterate persons.

Comment: The rules for multi-line statements are simply different in the shell versus a script - they have to be terminated by a blank line, and cannot contain a blank line.  There's nothing you can do to change this.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a workaround than a answer, but if you encapsulate **all** the code inside a if statement it will run as one "command". So you would turn this code:

```
if True:
 print('first')
print('second')
```

Into this code. And then it will run as one command:

```
if True:
 if True:
  print('first')
 print('second')
```